# how to pass input parameters to an angular 2 component from index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to set input, configuration parameters,  to a component that is not mentioned in index.html.

I can see how to do that for component selectors that are included in index.html.

How can I do from index.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your configuration in your Main module class as below

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}} Sample</h2>
      {{myConfiguration | json}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  myConfiguration:any=myConfiguration;
  constructor() {
    console.log(myConfiguration);
    this.name = 'Global Configuration'
  }
}

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App]
})
export class AppModule {
    var myConfiguration={id:1,devmode:true};  

}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cXwizPd5wxGJx3mEbN8G?p=preview)**